# Pentaho Report Designer: ' Fail on Error ' resets to undefined after close & reopen

Tags: reporting, pentaho

I get the warning:

```
WARNING: Element 'fullname_user' with expression on attribute 'value' has no value for mandatory property 'Fail On Error'.
```

The value is: =[firstname]&" "&[lastname]
When I go to properties > Optional > Fail On Error
I tag on ' True ' or ' False '

Save the report and close it. Then reopen it, and I get the warning again and the Fail On Error is back set to 'undefined'.

How do I solve this? Is there something that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: This is currently a bug in the PRD.
This will get fixed with next release for none enterprise users in the start of 2015.